# Using if to select between a super type and a subtype

Tags: java

If I have two classes namely `SuperType` and `SubType` where `SubType` extends `SuperType`, can I use `if` to detect the exact type at runtime?

My solution which does not work is as follows:

```
if (t instanceof SubType) 
    do SubType stuff
else
    do SuperType stuff
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. use the Reflection API.

```
if (SubType.class.isInstance(t)){
    // do SubType stuff
}else{
    // do SuperType stuff
}
```

More details here:

[Class.isInstance(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: What would be the point of using reflection if `SubType` is known at compile time?

Answer (score 6):

What Eran said is true, but using instanceof is a mistake if you can do this instead:

```
class SuperType {
    void doStuff(...) {
        ...do SuperType stuff...
    }
}

class SubType {
    @Override
    void doStuff(...) {
        ...do SubType stuff...
    }
}

SuperType t = methodThatMayReturnSuperTypeOrSubType(...);

t.doStuff();
```

Comment: I did come up with this idea but I have to write IO operations for a set of domain classes that have already been developed. Reflective code probably serves my purpose better.

Comment: Well, as Uncle Bob says, making decisions based on an object's type probably is the right thing to do if you're designing a system where it's likely you will add new methods in the future, and it's unlikely that you will add new types.  That _does_ sound like what you're up against--adding new functions on top of old code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `if` with an `instanceof` operator. However, doing so is usually a design smell because such decision should in most cases be left to the method dispatching mechanism. It makes sense if the types involved are not under your control so the option to add a method to those types is not available.

Comment: I am probably in the kind of situation you are describing. The subtypes and super types are entity classes that have already developed and tested. I have to write IO operations to read and write references contained in these objects and since the kind of operations performed changes according to the exact type of class, I am having to resort to `typeof`.

Answer (score 2):

You had a typo. It should be `instanceof`.

The syntax is :

```
if (t instanceof SubType) {
    //do SubType stuff
} else {
    //do SuperType stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Class getClass() method to detect the exact class at runtime.

```
if (t.getClass() == SubType.class) 
    do SubType stuff
else if (t.getClass() == SuperType.class) 
   do SuperType stuff
else do your stuff
```

Comment: reasons for downvoting please

Comment: Wrong, what if `t` is an instance of a `SubSubType`?

Comment: The point is you can easily use the getClass() method and use the == sign to compare Class objects,without the overhead of implementing new methods etc..See my edit now

Comment: @GaborSch The OP only talks about detecting of exact type at runtime

Comment: If there is a class `SubSubType` that extends `SubType`, then this statement goes to the `else` branch, instead of going to the *SubType* branch. Otherwise, you should **NEVER** compare `Class`es with `==` operator, the JVM has better built-in features for that.

Comment: I am replying with respect to OP "to detect the exact type at runtime?".There can be million of classes which can be extended and created.getClass() is the best way to determine the runtime Class.

Comment: If you stick to your interpretation, still use `equals()` to compare Object instances. `==` simply does not match the Java world. Otherwise I can accept your interpretation.
My interpretation was that OP wants to check that which case is happening: `SuperType` or `SubType`. But `SubSubType` falls to the `SubType` case.

Comment: @GaborSch Class Objects,Enum objects all use singleton Objects.They cannot be created even through reflection and all internally use the Object's class == way for comparing equality of Objects.

Comment: @GaborSch If you're saying one should never compare `Class`es for equality, I don't think that's correct.  There are legitimate use cases (see http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html for example).  If you're saying one should use `equals()` instead of `==`, it doesn't really matter--the `Class` class doesn't override `equals()` so it's still just a reference comparison.  So that would be just a style issue.

Comment: I also checked the source code from Oracle Java (1.7.0_45, to be more precise) and I've seen that in that version the `Class.equals()` falls back to `Object.equals()`. But as of my knowledge, there are more than  100 implementations of Java, and one cannot be absolutely sure sure that all implementations (including future ones) will always behave the same way. You an call it *style issue*, I'd call it *building on an unstable feature*.

Comment: BTW, the actual performance will be the same, because `Class.class` is final, so the body of its ˙equals()˙ method can be inlined to the caller place. So, most likely the bytecode will contain the code for  `==` on Oracle platform. Different compilers can behave differently.

Comment: @ajb I read through the referred article, but I haven't found examples of using `==` for class comparison. Just the opposite: I've seen `this.getClass().equals(that.getClass())` and `(other instanceof ColoredPoint)` code lines.